# Optimal Entry, Exit, And Stop Loss From Historical Stock Data

Tags: programming, stochastic-processes, historical-data, optimization

I'm trying to build a system that recommends stock trades. My goal is calculate optimal values for the following:

> 1. Entry Parameter: expressed as a percentage change downwards from the opening price. Our entry price = (opening price) * (1 - this
>    parameter). The first time the stock price reaches this price or
>    below, we will buy.
> 2. Stop Loss Parameter: expressed as a percentage change downwards from the entry price. Our stop loss = (entry price) * (1 - this parameter).
>    The first time the stock price reaches this price or below *while we
>    are long*, we will sell for a loss.
> 3. Exit Parameter: expressed as a percentage change upwards from the entry price. Our exit price = (entry price) * (1 + this parameter).
>    The first time the stock price reaches this price or above *while we
>    are long*, we will sell for a profit.

We are limited to one full trade per day. If we have bought, but not sold, by market close, we will sell at the closing price that day.

I would like to calculate these using historical data. That is, based on some number of trading days, I want to efficiently calculate values for these parameters that would have maximized my total return over those trading days.

I have already tried using scipy.optimize, but this takes too long to be useful. Is there another system I could utilize that would determine these values more efficiently? Is there an existing algorithm to determine this?

---

Addendum:
My historical data is stored as a list of Pandas DataFrames. Each DF is made up of 5 minute candles. Each row contains a timestamp (the end of that candle), as well as the Open, High, Low, and Close price for that candle. I am not married to this; other formats would be acceptable, if easier to work with.

Comment: Ah - yes I did. I have edited the question to reflect this

Comment: What I have seen people use is a sequential approach. First assume that the Stop Loss and Exit parameters are infinite, i.e. you hold every trade until the close. Experiment with a few values of the Entry Parameter (down 1%, down 2%, down 5%) and see what kind of profitability you can get. If it looks OK examine the distribution of P&L and see if a Stop Loss that cuts off some of the bigger losses helps cut drawdown without impacting profitability too much. Last you can experiment with a few values of Exit Param, but in my exp'nce it is best to allow these kinds of trades to continue until EOD

Comment: What a coincidence - this sequential approach is actually the one we ended up going with. I can anecdotally confirm your final sentiment. We've found that using this procedure to determine all 3 parameters is generally overfit. Fitting only entry and stop loss has typically yielded superior performance in validation datasets.